# How the the computation code is transferreed to dask worker from the client?

Tags: python, serialization, dask, dask-distributed

How does the client side source code get transferred to dask worker(s) ?

```
from dask.distributed  import Client


def hello3(a, b):
    print('I am hello 3')
    return a + 5 + b * 3


def hello2(a, b):
    print('I am hello2')
    return hello3(a * 10, b + 5)


def xadd(a, b):
    return hello2(a + 2, b * 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')
    x = client.submit(xadd, 1, 2)
    print(x.result())
```

In the above code snippet, how will submit transfer code for xadd, hello2 and hello3 functions to the workers ?

Answer (score 1):

Dask uses `pickle` for sending most things from the client the scheduler, which then sends stuff on to workers. In the case of code defined in `__main__`, you will (very likely) end up falling back to `cloudpickle`, which is a similar protocol that's able to cope with a wider variety of situations.

> Among other things, cloudpickle supports pickling for lambda functions along with functions and classes defined interactively in the `__main__` module (for instance in a script, a shell or a Jupyter notebook).

( https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle#readme )

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. This link is helpful too https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/protocol.html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that the following is a correct description, but might give some useful leads:

Upon submission of the function and arguments via `client.submit`, `dask` will serialize the function and arguments (as well as any additional kwargs). The description of the serialization is provided in the [docs](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/serialization.html).

The specific function used to extract the function code is the [`_get_computation_code`](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/9b9f948b8143fee43887a941a3304273beed4a50/distributed/client.py#L3004) method.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I am debugging the code and finding it difficult to figure out where code serialization is happening.  For the code snippet I have pasted here, https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/9b9f948b8143fee43887a941a3304273beed4a50/distributed/client.py#L3004 is returning early (from line number 3017 in client.py),  returning an empty tuple (because nframes == 0).